# How to fix the error while saving the image in gallery?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-intent

I was trying to save an image in a gallery via an app.

this is the error I got

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for a provider with authority com.example.android.fileprovider
```

I have a button which would capture an image from the camera by calling the below function.

**Code for saving the image **

```
 val REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1

    private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
            // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
            takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                val photoFile: File? = try {
                    createImageFile()
                } catch (ex: IOException) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    Log.i("Exception","${ex.toString()}")
                    null
                }
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                photoFile?.also {
                    val photoURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                        this,
                        "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                        it
                    )
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    lateinit var currentPhotoPath: String

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun createImageFile(): File {
        // Create an image file name
        val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
        val storageDir: File? = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        return File.createTempFile(
            "JPEG_${timeStamp}_", /* prefix */
            ".jpg", /* suffix */
            storageDir /* directory */
        ).apply {
            // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
            currentPhotoPath = absolutePath
        }
    }
```

Now I in google docs I found out that we need to add some more lines in **Manifest.xml** file, so I added them, but still, there is an error

```
<?XML version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.intentexperiment">


    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_ALARM" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <provider

            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <external-files-path
            android:name="image" android:path="Android/data/com.example.package.name/files/Pictures" />
    </paths>
```

I don't understand where the error is.

**EDIT**

I have moved the

```
<path>
...
</path>
```

in an XML file and accordingly changed the android: resource attribute
but the error now is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.intentexperiment-l0jZknwE-m3bgGza6RJAug==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.intentexperiment-l0jZknwE-m3bgGza6RJAug==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
```

**EDIT 2**

after doing this

```
  android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
```

still there is a error

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.intentexperiment/files/Pictures/JPEG_20200425_194311_3114424866623330911.jpg
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:744)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:418)
        at com.example.intentexperiment.MainActivity.dispatchTakePictureIntent(MainActivity.kt:54)
        at com.example.intentexperiment.MainActivity.access$dispatchTakePictureIntent(MainActivity.kt:22)
        at com.example.intentexperiment.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:31)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6600)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6577)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:781)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25912)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
```

Comment: Please paste your "@xml/file_paths

Comment: `<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="image" path=""Android/data/com.example.package.name/files/Pictures"" />
</paths> `